# How do I push new element with the given text to an array of selected html elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is selected HTML elements:

```
var array = jQuery.makeArray($(".dersprg tr td:nth-child(6)"));
```

this selects some table data which consists of table header text and some irrelevant data. I can interpret the irrelevant data using if statements and extract the information i need, but i can not push it to the array since the types are not the same I suppose. Code is like this:

```
for(i=0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
    content = array[i].innerHTML;
    if(some conditions){
        array.splice(i--,1);    //eliminate non day elements
        array.push('test input <br>');  //problematic line
    }
}
```

You see, i use `innerHTML` to compare the content of selected `<td>` element, but when it comes to adding some `test input` the whole array renders empty. I think this is due to type mismatch, but i could not figure out how i can solve this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you need this array for?

Comment: an array of strings won't be the same thing as an array of `<td>`s

Comment: I don't think "type" is your problem since you can add different "types" to an array.  For example `a = []; a.push(10); a.push({}); a.push("hello"); a.push(false);` will give you `[1, 
Object
, "hello", false]`.

Comment: type seems not the problem. But i cannot add `<td>test input <br></td>` either. how am i supposed to add such an entry?

@Blender the long story is, i am trying to get the days stored in a table such as [this](http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb=BIO), and eliminate the non-day data, repeating data and process the multi-day-valued table data such as `BIO 112E General Biology II` row in the table given above. What i basically intend to  do is to get to the multi-day-entries(done) and add the non existent day into the `days` array(fail). Adding is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var cell=document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode('test input <br>') );
array.push(cell);
```

This will insert a `<td>` in the array instead of a string.

Comment: Okay, got another tiny question tho. When i `alert(cell.innerHTML);` i get `test input &lt;br&gt;`. i need to get `< and >` not `&lt; or &gt;`. What must i do?

Comment: You're welcome :) you could use `unesacape(cell.innerHTML)` or `decodeURIComponent(cell.innerHTML)` to get `<` and `>`, as `&lt;` and `&gt;` are html "escaped" characters

Comment: When am i supposed to call those methods? I tried calling after appendChild and before push, i tried calling `unescape(cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode('test input <br>')));` however when `alert` is invoked i still get `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: `cell.appendChild` is the action involved in the creation of the cell, you more likely want to manipulate a string (ie: his `innerHTML` or `textContent`)